# Cooperatively pausing async methods

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library, pause

I am using a Task for a long-running asynchronous processing operation that I want to be able to pause and resume at arbitrary moments. Luckily for me one of the TPL's own authors at Microsoft already came up with a [solution to this problem](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods/). The only trouble is his solution doesn't work properly.

When you take out the `await Task.Delay(100)` in the code below, the code will stop honoring pause requests after the very first one. It appears the `SomeMethodAsync` code resumes execution on the same thread as the other task if the value of `Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` is to be believed. Also the output of `SomeMethodAsync` suggests that it is running on several threads.

I have always found the TPL rather confusing and difficult to work with and async/await even more so, so I am having a hard time understanding what's even going on here. I'd be very grateful if anyone could explain.

Minimalist example code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PauseTokenTest {
    class Program {
        static void Main() {
            var pts = new PauseTokenSource();
            Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true) {
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(
                        $"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: Pausing task");
                    pts.IsPaused = !pts.IsPaused;
                }
            });
            SomeMethodAsync(pts.Token).Wait();
        }

        public static async Task SomeMethodAsync(PauseToken pause) {
            for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
                Console.WriteLine($"{Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}: {i}");

                // Comment this out and repeatedly pausing and resuming will no longer work.
                await Task.Delay(100);

                await pause.WaitWhilePausedAsync();
            }
        }
    }

    public class PauseTokenSource {
        internal static readonly Task s_completedTask =
            Task.FromResult(true);
        volatile TaskCompletionSource<bool> m_paused;

        public bool IsPaused {
            get { return m_paused != null; }
            set {
                if (value) {
                    Interlocked.CompareExchange(
                        ref m_paused, new TaskCompletionSource<bool>(), null);
                } else {
                    while (true) {
                        var tcs = m_paused;
                        if (tcs == null) return;
                        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref m_paused, null, tcs) == tcs) {
                            tcs.SetResult(true);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public PauseToken Token { get { return new PauseToken(this); } }

        internal Task WaitWhilePausedAsync() {
            var cur = m_paused;
            return cur != null ? cur.Task : s_completedTask;
        }
    }

    public struct PauseToken {
        readonly PauseTokenSource m_source;
        internal PauseToken(PauseTokenSource source) {
            m_source = source;
        }

        public bool IsPaused {
            get { return m_source != null && m_source.IsPaused; }
        }

        public Task WaitWhilePausedAsync() {
            return IsPaused ? m_source.WaitWhilePausedAsync() :
                PauseTokenSource.s_completedTask;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a race condition. It should be `static async Task Main()`

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks but I'm getting the same results.

Comment: Yes, you also need to get rid of `.Wait()`. Use `await` instead.

Comment: I would suggest to try using the `PauseTokenSource` from the [Nito.AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/) package (by Stephen Cleary), and see if the problem persists.

Comment: My wild guess is that the problem is related with the `TaskCompletionSource<bool>` not being initialized with the `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` option.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods I tried that but it doesn't make any difference. Also this code is taken directly from the author's blog so I assume it should be correct?

Comment: _"Also this code is taken directly from the author's blog so I assume it should be correct?"_ that's sweet of you, but no. You shouldn't assume that. Even if it once was, it may not be any more... even MS documentation examples are notoriously famous for low quality code for anything that's not directly the subject of the example.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thanks, that fixes it! If you make it answer I can accept it as the solution.

Comment: @Fildor-standswithMods no I agree with you, the quality of MSDN documentation and Microsoft's own code and APIs has been going downhill rapidly over the last years.

Comment: I haven't studied your code, so I can't post an answer. You could consider posting a [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) if you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because of the way task continuations are executed. In many places in the framework, task continuations are executed synchronously when possible. It's [not always possible](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/when-executesynchronously-doesnt-execute-synchronously/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058), but one place where it does become common is on thread pool threads, which are often treated as though they're exchangeable.

[`await` is one of those places where synchronous continuations are used](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/12/dont-block-in-asynchronous-code.html); this is not officially documented anywhere AFAIK but I describe the behavior on my blog.

So, what is essentially happening is this: `SomeMethodAsync` is paused (`await`ing the task returned from `WaitWhilePausedAsync` - without a context), which attaches the rest of `SomeMethodAsync` as a continuation on that task. Then when the `Task.Run` (thread pool) thread toggles `IsPaused`, it completes the task that was returned from `WaitWhilePausedAsync`. The runtime then looks at the context associated with that continuation (none), so that continuation is considered compatible with any thread pool thread. And hey, the *current thread* is a thread pool thread! So it just runs the continuation directly.

The fun part about that is that without *another* `await`, the `SomeMethodAsync` method becomes entirely synchronous: it always retrieves an already-completed task from `WaitWhilePausedAsync`, so it just continues executing its infinite loop forever. As a reminder, [`await` behaves synchronously with already-completed tasks](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) (as I describe on my blog). This infinite loop is running *within* the `IsPaused` setter, so the `Task.Run` code never continues its loop to call `ReadLine` again.

If `SomeMethodAsync` *does* have an `await`, then it can behave asynchronously, returning back to its caller (completing the continuation), and allowing the `Task.Run` loop to continue executing.

As suggested by Theodor Zoulias, passing the `TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously` flag to the `TaskCompletionSource<bool>` will also work. In that case, the task continuation is run asynchronously (on a separate thread pool thread), rather than executed directly on the calling thread.

IIRC, the [blog post you referenced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/cooperatively-pausing-async-methods/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) predates the `RunContinuationsAsynchronously` flag. It also predates the (non-generic) `TaskCompletionSource`.

Also as suggested by Theodor Zoulias, I have a `PauseTokenSource` in my [Nito.AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx/) library that avoids this issue. It also uses `RunContinuationsAsynchronously`.

Comment: Also: interesting timing for this question! It so happens I am [giving a talk](https://that.us/activities/9h2sITZbUA8BZwaXEoBw/?utm_content=249202691&hss_channel=tw-184857087&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter&utm_campaign=Wisconsin%20%2723) next week that includes implementing a pause token, among other advanced async topics.